# Android HttpClient with XML issue

Tags: android, xml, httpclient

I have problem at Android HTTPClient.

I am converting iOS app into Android.
here is the iOS code.

```
NSURL *uri = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:uri];
[request appendPostData:[strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request startSynchronous];
```

it returns XML data correctly.

and here is the android code.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);

httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(strData, "UTF-8");
entity.setContentType("text/xml");
httppost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

but web server returns html data which is same when I call url without xml.

I have double checked the url and strdata is exactly same at iOS and Android;

Can you help me what I made mistake.

Many thanks.

Comment: What kind of HTML content is the server returning ? could it be a 4xx or 5xx error page ?

Comment: yes it returns 1 page of html error page, but if request is correct, server should return XML contents.